# Getting product name and phone number in the success page for Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9 and I need to use customer name, number, and product name in the success page. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

get customer name and phone number using below fields

```
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());
  if($order->getCustomerIsGuest()){
     echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
     echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
  }
  else{
     echo $order->getCustomerName();
     echo $order->getTelephone();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the order object in success page

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(); 
$order->getCustomerName();
$ordered_items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($ordered_items as $item)
  $product_name[] = $item->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if some one searching for same.

```
$orderDetails = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
```

To get Contact Number

```
echo $telePhone=$orderObj->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

To get Complete array use `print_r($orderDetails);`